# Flutter Web - get asset image as File()

Tags: flutter-web

I am using a third party library that requires I pass U8IntList to display an image in a PDF. Their examples has me obtain the image in a File and read the bytes out.

```
PdfBitmap(file.readAsBytesSync())
```

This system is great when I am obtaining an image from a server, but I want to display an image stored in local assets.

What I tried to implement was this code..

```
 Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {

    final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');
    final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');
    await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

    return file;
  }
```

Which returns the error 'No implementation found for method getTemporaryDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider'.

If anyone knows how to get an Asset Image as File on web it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to write byte data to a file just to read it again? Just directly pass your byte data to the constructor that requires it. This should be changed on both your web *and* mobile implementations as it will end up being far faster.

```dart
final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');
PdfBitmap(byteData.buffer.asUint8List())
```

Comment: I think I tried something similar but didn't know how to get byteData to Uint8List. Smart and simple solution, much appreciated.